# sha256sum: 'standard input': no file was verified

Tags: kali-linux

I am installing the PhoneInfoga using the following command but it gives me this error:

> sha256sum: 'standard input': no file was verified

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sundowndev/phoneinfoga/master/support/scripts/install | bash

Installing PhoneInfoga
Found version v2.4.1
Downloading version v2.4.1...
--2022-01-19 03:25:34--  https://github.com/sundowndev/phoneinfoga/releases/download/v2.4.1/PhoneInfoga_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.121.3
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.121.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/154643390/021186ce-7b40-4038-ad57-d1e45dd68793?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20220119%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220119T082542Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=13262d3f6cf2654ca8e22cfaabbb8555f78a21bfd8e917118d77e89114977384&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=154643390&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dphoneinfoga_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream [following]
--2022-01-19 03:25:35--  https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/154643390/021186ce-7b40-4038-ad57-d1e45dd68793?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20220119%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220119T082542Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=13262d3f6cf2654ca8e22cfaabbb8555f78a21bfd8e917118d77e89114977384&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=154643390&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dphoneinfoga_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
Resolving objects.githubusercontent.com (objects.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.108.133, 185.199.110.133, 185.199.109.133, ...
Connecting to objects.githubusercontent.com (objects.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.108.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6188940 (5.9M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘PhoneInfoga_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz’

PhoneInfoga_Linux_x86_6 100%[==============================>]   5.90M  2.46MB/s    in 2.4s    

2022-01-19 03:25:38 (2.46 MB/s) - ‘PhoneInfoga_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz’ saved [6188940/6188940]

Verifying checksum...
sha256sum: 'standard input': no file was verified
```

Comment: *Never*  do `curl | sh`-style commands, you have no knowledge about what is being executed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

that is because installation script is downloaded file '**P**hone**I**nfoga_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz' (note the uppercase "P" and "I"), while the *PhoneInfoga_checksums.txt* file is containing hash of the same file in lowercase characters "p" and "i" in '**p**hone**i**nfoga_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz';

therfore `sha256sum` command don't find the same fileName matching on that checksum with the downloaded one and it reports *`sha256sum: 'standard input': no file was verified`* since no files were matched and then it stops executing the rest of the instalation script as it's written.

Solutions:

1. manually check your downloaded file `sha256sum PhoneInfoga_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz` and verify with the checksum from the *PhoneInfoga_checksums.txt* file and execute `tar xfv "PhoneInfoga_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz"` after that to finish the installation.
2. download installation script and rename downloaded file before checking the checksum step to match the fileName in the *PhoneInfoga_checksums.txt* file.